# Style for a specific result in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, css, foreach

I'm trying to make a border and change the color/font for '111' result(check picture).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Htt.jpg

The thing is that the categories are displayed from a foreach that connects with the mysql database :

```
<?php $class = (isset($category) || isset($manufacturer)) ? ' categories_hide' : ''; ?>
<div class="hidden-xs block categories <?php echo $class; ?>">
    <h2><a id="menu_all_categories" href="#">Category</a></h2>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul id="menu">
        <?php foreach ($categories as $_category):?>
            <li><?php echo link_to($_category['title'].'<span> ('.$_category['num_products'].')</span>', '@category?category_alias='. $_category['slug'].'-c'.$_category['id'], array('title' => $_category['title']));?></li>
        <?php endforeach;?>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: after `</li>`add `<hr>`   example:- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_hr_test

Comment: If i would do that , I would change the style of all category names. I only want to change '111' style.

Comment: Add if else and provide some css stuff by adding class to li of 111

Comment: This is what I'm asking for . How can I add class to only '111' if I'm getting all 3 categories through that foreach?

Comment: check the answer  and change the `if` condition variable accordingly